# Eclipse Video Intent video

Tags: java, android, eclipse, video, android-intent

I'm quite new to this, I have checked for an answer at the forums here but I didn't find any answer that can really help me out. I'm trying to play a video from the res/raw folder. I have set up this code so far:

```
MediaPlayer mp; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    //Starts up a new activity, based on what listitem you press.
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(VideoButtonActivity.this, com.example.norskattrack.VideoActivity.class);                                 

      if(position==0){
        System.out.println("Item 0");

        intent.putExtra("video", 1);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
      if(position==1){
        System.out.println("Item 1");

        intent.putExtra("video", 2);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Update; If I was not clear on what I needed help with; I need to play a video from the resource file, and add (obviously) a method to do so. I thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package.app/raw/videoname");
```

That should let you play the video from the raw folder !

have a look at :

[How to play videos in android from assets folder or raw folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028717/how-to-play-videos-in-android-from-assets-folder-or-raw-folder)

[Play Video From Raw Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580813/play-video-from-raw-folder)

[Trying to play video from raw folder (VideoView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609219/trying-to-play-video-from-raw-folder-videoview)

All have excellent answers !

Comment: Thank you. This helped. Will be sure to spend more time on browing Stackoverflow for good answers.