# How to Play Video from asset in Webview Android

Tags: android

my activity_main.xml

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

my main activity

```
ws = (WebSettings) wb.getSettings();
wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.loadUrl("File:///android_asset/www/html5.html");
```

myhtml

```
<source src="playlist.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

i'm load video from asset. directory my video asset/www/playlist.mp4
but it's not working..

Comment: why not use VideoView instead?

Comment: VideoView? what is that? any example? Thanks

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020270/where-to-place-local-video-files-for-android-webview-html5-hybrid-app

Comment: what is Data Type of video? Thanks :)

Comment: Anyone is not helping but distracting him to use a videoview !
he just simply want to play video in webview. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978961/how-to-play-html5-video-and-youtube-video-within-android-webview?rq=1) try this..

Answer (score 1):

Better You use `VideoView`

```
VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
  setContentView(videoHolder);
  Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
    + R.raw.splash); // you file name
  videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
```

[Reference Link to follow](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/06/how-to-play-video-from-resources.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339101/2591002)

Comment: res.getString(R.string.XXXXXX) it's url?

Comment: your link don't exist :D

Answer (score 1):

**How to Play Video from asset in Webview Android.**

```
we can't play video in webview from asset folder. even its very difficult to play video 
from server url in webview. all we can do is to make a custom HTML5 webview and then we  
can play.but this is very long process.
```

## Suggestion and Solution

Its better to use videoview provided by android.and  put your video in raw folder not in assets.use the below code to play video from Raw folder in your app:

```
  getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
  VideoView _view= new VideoView(this);
  _view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
  Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
  + R.raw.your_raw_file); //add file without any extension
  _view.setVideoURI(video);
  setContentView(_view);
  _view.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a different approach. Instead of putting the video into the assets folder, I base64 encode it and put it directly into the html file / source code.
Since videos in the assets folders are fix, they won't change anyway, and neither does the html file probably. Therefore, why not put the video directly into the html page. 
The effect is the same, and it works without problems.

Example: http://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/video.php

Base64 Encoder (online): http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/

(It doesn't really answer the question about video playback from the assets folder, but the result is the same imho.)

Comment: That's an interesting approach.